# remove empty lines from a file in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way in javascript in which you can remove the empty lines from a text. And if there is, is the only option iterating over the text to check if there is an empty line or is there a straightforward way. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.
For example:

```
This 
is 

an

example
```

would change to

```
this
is
an
example
```

some rough code:

```
var aStr = 'this\nis\n\nan\n\nexample'
var myre = (/[\r\n]+/g, '\n\n');
var bStr = aStr.replace(myre,"");
//string with no empty line
console.log(bStr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate the lines and filter over them.

```js
let str = `This
is

an

example`;
let res = str.split('\n').filter(Boolean).join('\n');
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
text = `This 
is 

an

example`

cleaned_text = text.split('\n').filter(x=> x !== '').join('\n');
```

The split makes an array with the text separated by the '\n' token, then filters the empty strings and then join again with an '\n' character

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`String.prototype.replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) with a RegExp pattern to get what you need:

```
const str = `This 
is 

an

example`;
console.log(str.replaceAll(/\n\n+/ig, `\n`, str);
```